# HTML/CSS when I change browser width to small or xs for tablets and mobile size, contents do not fit

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```css
body{
 background-image: url(https://www.ucalgary.ca/mediacentre/files/mediacentre/aerials_011a7179_fe.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 font-family: 'Numans', sans-serif;
}
html, body{
 height: 100%;
}
.container{
 height: 100%;
 align-content: center;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.card{
 height: 370px;
 margin: 10% auto auto 30%;
 width: 450px;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
 border-radius: 10px;

}
.card-header h3{
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 40px;
 font-size: 30px;
}
.card-header h4{
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 50px;
 font-size: 20px;
}
.login_btn{
 color: black;
 background-color: #FFC312;
 border-color: #FFC312;
 width:100px;
 padding: 12px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 margin-left: 180px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 font-family: 'Numans', sans-serif;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.login_btn:hover{
 color:black;
 background-color: white;
 border-color: white;

.card{
   height: calc(100vh - 20%);
   margin: 10% 15% 0 15%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>University of Calgary Scholarship</title>
 <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
 <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="selectionPage.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
 

</head>
<body>
 <div class = "container">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center h-100">
   <div class = "card">
    <div class ="card-header">
     <h3>University of Calgary Scholarship Page</h3>
     <h4>Please Select One</h4>
    </div>
    <div class = "card-body">
     <div class = "form-group">
      <form action="studentLogin.html">
       <input type = "submit" value = "Student" class= "btn float-left login_btn">
      </form>
      <form action="adminLogin.html">
       <input type = "submit" value = "Administrator" class= "btn float-right login_btn">
      </form>
     </div>     
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have adjusted some of my code from my previous post but now when I shrink the width of my window, the contents do not adjust to the screen width. The container at a screen size of small or tablet and xs or mobile, half of it will not be visible. I have added some code at the end of my css file according to what another user has suggested. And it makes it better but still does not completely work at the small and xs level.

Thank You
.........................................................................

Comment: Your background taking time to load could be due to the image size, try compressing it.
If you don't want to sacrifice quality then consider adding a pre-loader to your sight so your assets including images will be loaded in before the user sees your site.

Answer (score 3):

Add this property and it should works as expected :

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d3thj5g0/1/)

Also, the image you use is very large (6144 x 4096 pixels) so it can take some times to load. You can resize it to max 2000 px of width and compress it with tools like TinyPng :

https://tinypng.com/

**EDIT**

You can use `flex`properties to handle the alignment of the `.card`

```
.d-flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/61mrwj3q/1/)

Comment: That works! Any suggestions on how to fix when the screen shrinks to mobile size or xs that the container fits inside?

Comment: Yes, with flex properties, you can do that, see my updated answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Vincent G solution, I changed the following lines for your latest comment:

```
.card{
   height: calc(100vh - 20%);
   margin: 10% 15% 0 15%;
}
```

[See the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkurzweil/eaxphsq3/6/)

Browser support for [calc](https://caniuse.com/#search=calc) and [viewport](https://caniuse.com/#search=viewport)

**EDIT 1**

In your updated code snippet you don't need my above mentioned code snippet.

Basically, you break the responsiveness by using fixed `height` of your class `.card` and pretty much the same mistake on your `input` fields. (`margin-left` and `width`)

[See the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkurzweil/zhwq5gem/9/) (I marked the changes in the fiddle!)

I hope this will solve your problem :)

Comment: I had to change some of my code. And now even if I do this, it won't resize the container to fit the smallest width like mobile screen. I've updated my code above.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is the standard **HTML** and **CSS** code!

```css
body{
 background-image: url(https://www.ucalgary.ca/mediacentre/files/mediacentre/aerials_011a7179_fe.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 font-family: 'Numans', sans-serif;
}
html, body{
 height: 100%;
}
.container{
 height: 100%;
 align-content: center;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.card{
 height: 370px;
 margin: 10% auto ;
 width: 450px;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
 border-radius: 10px;

}
.card-header h3{
 color: #000;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 40px;
 font-size: 30px;
}
.card-header h4{
 color: #000;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 50px;
 font-size: 20px;
}
.login_btn{
 color: black;
 background-color: #FFC312 !important;
 border-color: #FFC312;
 padding: 12px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 margin-left: 0;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 font-family: 'Numans', sans-serif;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.login_btn:hover{
 color:black;
 background-color: white;
 border-color: white;

.card{
   height: calc(100vh - 20%);
   margin: 10% 15% 0 15%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>University of Calgary Scholarship</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 

</head>
<body>
 <div class = "container">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center h-100">
   <div class = "card">
    <div class ="card-header">
     <h3>University of Calgary Scholarship Page</h3>
     <h4>Please Select One</h4>
    </div>
    <div class = "card-body">
     <div class = "form-group text-center">
      <form action="studentLogin.html">
       <input type = "submit" value = "Student" class= "btn login_btn"> <form>
      
      <form action="adminLogin.html">
       <input type = "submit" value = "Administrator" class= "btn login_btn">
      </form>
     </div>     
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```